# jinja2 load template from string: TypeError: no loader for this environment specified

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 in Flask. I want to render a template from a string. I tried the following 2 methods:

```
 rtemplate = jinja2.Environment().from_string(myString)
 data = rtemplate.render(**data)
```

and

```
 rtemplate = jinja2.Template(myString)
 data = rtemplate.render(**data)
```

However both methods return:

```
TypeError: no loader for this environment specified
```

I checked the manual and this url: https://gist.github.com/wrunk/1317933

However nowhere is specified to select a loader when using a string.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can provide `loader` in `Environment` from [that list](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#loaders)

```
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader

rtemplate = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(myString)
data = rtemplate.render(**data)
```

**Edit**: The problem was with `myString`, it has `{% include 'test.html' %}` and Jinja2 has no idea where to get template from.

**UPDATE**

As @iver56 kindly noted, it's better to:

```
rtemplate = Environment(loader=BaseLoader()).from_string(myString)
```

Comment: When trying this I get the error: AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute 'get_source'

Comment: @user3605780 i slightly edited code, but it change nothing, and it works on my machine. What version of `jinja2` are you using?

Comment: I get the same error, I was using version 2.7.3, I just upgraded to 2.8 and there I get the error: TypeError: get_source() missing 1 required positional argument: 'template'

Comment: I think it should be in the string itself. It works when I just test it with myString='abc'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122508/discussion-between-vishes-shell-and-user3605780).

Comment: It was a problem with {% include 'test.html' %}. I solved this by first redering test.html and inserting this as a variable in the string template.

Comment: As far as I know, `Environment(loader=BaseLoader())` is more correct than `Environment(loader=BaseLoader)`

Comment: @iver56 i'm not quite sure, firstly i thought you are right, but then i went to source files and `BaseLoader` don't have `__init__` method, so it's probably no sense to call `BaseLoader()`, because it wont fire `__init__()`.

Comment: BaseLoader extends `object`, so it has an `__init__` function. You are right in that `__init__` doesn't do much, but that's not the main point here. The point is having an instance of BaseLoader rather than just referring to the class.

Comment: @iver56 you're right! Updated answer, thank you! Cheers!

Comment: Without wishing to be pedantic, I would imagine that `from_string` is a class method (i.e. is declared with a `@classmethod` decorator) and designed to be called from the class. Since it's a factory  method there is surely no point in creating an instance just to call its method and throw it away? OK, maybe I _am_ being pedantic, but it could be important when instance creation is expensive.

Comment: Instance creation might be expensive, but what you're buying, among other things, is thread safety. It's better to find other ways to optimize that don't compromise sound engineering principals

Comment: @holdenweb `from_string` is not a class method, so you must instantiate.

Answer (score 17):

When I came to this question, I wanted [FileSystemLoader](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/api/#loaders):

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
with open("templates/some_template.html") as f:
    template_str = f.read()
template = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("templates/")).from_string(template_str)
html_str = template.render(default_start_page_lanes=default_start_page_lanes,
                           **data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the `FileSystemLoader`, but that didn't immediately work for me. My code was all in a module (a subdirectory with an `__init__.py` file), so I was able to use [`PackageLoader`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.PackageLoader) instead. The Jinja documentation calls this ["the simplest way" to configure templates](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.Environment):

```
my-proj
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
└── app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── app.py
    ├── constants.py
    └── templates
        ├── base.html.jinja
        └── macros.html.jinja
```

```python
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader


def generate_html(my_list):
    env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader("app"))
    template = env.get_template("base.html.jinja")

    return template.render({ "stuff": my_list })
```